# React native how to upload multiple images to server (backend)

Tags: file-upload, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-image-picker

for single Image upload working but multiple images upload not working

```
     const data = new FormData();
//sending data to backend in the form of array 
  
   data.append("media_files", [{
                      uri: item.uri,
                      type: item.mime,
                      name: item.name || `filename${i}.jpg`,
                    }]);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Working Properly now**

```
  const [selectedImages, setSelectedImages] = useState(imageData)
     const data = new FormData();
    
    //images selected from image picker(react-native-image-crop-picker) library 
    
    selectedImages.forEach((item, i) => {
      data.append("media_files[]", {
        uri: item.uri,
        type: "image/jpeg",
        name: item.filename || `filename${i}.jpg`,
      });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This saved a lot of time